# Removing / Overlaying logo on mp4 video format with ffmpeg on linux

Tags: linux, video, filter, ffmpeg, video-processing

I'm trying to remove a logo from an .mp4 video file with ffmpeg on linux machine without re-encoding (for preserving the same quality) with the following command:

```
ffmpeg -i input.mp4 -vf delogo=x=270:y=190:w=40:h=40 -c:a copy output.mp4
```

and it gives me the following errors:

```
Unrecognized option 'vf'
```

then a new error came up:

```
Unable to find a suitable output format for 'delogo=x=270:y=190:w=40:h=40'
```

ffmpeg is always updating and it seems that they change command line arguments a lot so any material or tutorial I find online seems to get outdated quickly ...

I reviewed the documentation but can't get it to work, I think I'm missing something...?

So: What is the correct command line in linux shell? Also, how to view or find out the exact coordinates of the area to be removed before actually removing the logo? And how can I overlay a solid color in a certain area instead of removing the logo transparently?

Comment: Filtering requires re-encoding of the stream being filtered, but I guess you were referring to the audio being stream copied.

Comment: Thank you for your note @LordNeckbeard I will review that part and rephrase the re-encoding argument again...making sure its for video , I also discovered i'm using an old version of ffmpeg.

Answer (score 2):

> Unrecognized option 'vf'

What version of ffmpeg? (You should be able to tell from the output of running just "ffmpeg" without arguments.) My guess is that you have a terribly old version, "-vf" is still current syntax.

Comment: you are correct @Ronald S. Bultje, I'm using an older version of ffmpeg that is shipped with my Linux dist.
I'm in the process of downloading the latest version from the ffmpeg website...

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

put the delogo phrase in quotation marks: "delogo=x=270:y=190:w=40:h=40"